# Least squares aproximation

Tags: calculus, functions

In a Problem of least squares aproximation of a function 
$f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$, 
in an interval $[a, b]$  by a polynomial of degree $n$

$$p(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\ldots+c_nx^n,\;\;\;\;\;\;c_n\neq 0,$$

we have to minimize the function $\psi$ defined by 
$$\psi(c_0, c_1,\ldots, c_n)=\int_a^b|f(x)-p(x)|^2dx. $$

It is customary to solve the problem as follows:

Solve the system: $$\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial c_i}=0,\;\;\;\;for\;i=0,\ldots, n,$$

then the solution of this system is the minimum. My question is:

Why  the point where the partial derivatives are zero is the minimum and not the maximum or an inflection point?

Answer (score 1):

The least squares solutions are a convex set. ([The set of least squares solutions is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353453/derivative-to-zero-what-does-it-intuitively-mean/2165805#2165805)). Therefore the extrema are minima.